# How to "print" a PDF on a Mac so that is automatically sent by AirDrop to an iOS device?

Tags: macos, ios, automator, printing, airdrop

I heavily use my iPad Pro with pencil to go paperless. This works perfectly, but printing to paper from any Mac app is still much simpler than printing to the "paper-replacement", meaning to an iPad app. I am therefore looking for a mechanism to make this equally simple.

Currently, I open the "Print" dialog in any Mac program, click on "Open PDF in Preview", then in the Preview app "Share via AirDrop", wait a moment until my iPad appears, find it, click it and then select on the iPad into which application to copy the document.

Is there a way to automate this? Automator on Mac has no "share via AirDrop" action (even though it was announced on the WWDC a while ago).

Comment: Since my macbook is too old to properly use AirDrop I make do with DropBox. However, if I had to cobble up a solution I would make a "hot folder" (by using folder actions: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html) that fires up AirDrop every time an item is dropped into it (some references could be: https://qsapp.com/wiki/Open_AirDrop_(AppleScript) and https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/libraries/examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, this only seems to open up the AirDrop dialog, so the remaining process is still manual.

Comment: as I said, I cannot test Airdrop because it doesn't work for me... did you try to record your actions with the Script Editor to check if the Finder executes any specific recordable actions?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually use iCloud & iCloud Drive, Print to PDF and then save the PDF to iCloud and it will show on your iPad. Thats why iCloud Drive is there.

Or if you just have to use AirDrop, then:

Why not print to PDF then share the PDF via AirDrop?

It appears to be much easier using either method than to create an automation to get the same effects.

Comment: iCloud Drive is not supported by the Apps I am using. I currently print to PDF and send the doc via AirDrop. But this process is cumbersome. I'd like to find an easier way, since I am doing this multiple times a day.

Comment: You can send the file to iCloud drive. When you print to pdf save the PDF file to your desktop then go to iCloud.com and sign in, click on iCloud drive and upload it. iCloud drive supports pdf files easily.